# MVC5 ViewModel binding in HTTP GET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, internationalization, model-binding

I have an action like this

```
public ActionResult Overview(TimeAxisVM TimeAxis = null)
{
    return View(new OverviewVM());
}
```

View model like this

```
public class TimeAxisVM
{
    // omitted ctor

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? From { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? To { get; set; }
}
```

An editor template for the view model

```
@model TimeAxisVM

@using (Html.BeginForm("Overview", "Controller", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.From)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.To)

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

And a view for the Overview action like this

```
@model OverviewVM

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TimeAxis)
```

When I execute the GET request this is the query string is TimeAxis.From=22.+02.+2014&TimeAxis.To=25.+02.+2014 but once in the action TimeAxis.From and TimeAxis.To are both null.

If I change the form method to POST it immediately works as expected. From design point of view this should/has to be a GET request.

Any ideas how to make the model binding work for GET?

UPDATE:

Changing the action to

```
public ActionResult Overview(DateTime? From = null, DateTime? To = null)
```

and sending the request in this form: .../Overview/?From=22.+02.+2014&To=25.+02.+2014 works as well.

But I'd like to keep it encapsulated in the class and dont need to change the input field name - EditorFor generates them as TimeAxis.From and TimeAxis.To. I might add other properties to the ViewModel/form.

Comment: 22.+02.+2014 is not a valid date string.  You need to format it as something like 22-02-2014.  Either that, or you will have to create a custom model binder to parse your parameters

Comment: It is valid in my locale, they parse fine. And as I said, if I use POST it works. Unless the space gets encoded differently, not with '+'

Comment: What locale is that?  I've never hear of a date string formatted with both spaces and periods like that.

Comment: As far as I can tell the values are the same, whether using GET or POST. I as well tried sending (with GET) the value 22.+02.+2014 to an action with a DateTime param directly, works without a problem.

Comment: The locale is cs-CZ. But it makes no difference.

Comment: If that is your actual code.. "Controller" is not a valid name for a controller, it must be something + Controller.  In any event, I just created a sample with your code (although I used a real controller name) and it worked fine for me, including the spaces.. although I used my locale format.  Are you sure your server is correctly configured for your locale?

Comment: It's not an actual Controller. Again, it works with the only change of FormMethod.Get to FormMethod.Post

Comment: Well, since you won't include your REAL code, we probably can't help you, since it's probably an error with your real code.

Comment: It's not that much different. I've only omitted other html (which is outside of the form) and styling and the Overview action does more than just returning view. The request strings are accurate.

Comment: And yet when I create a sample project that does exactly what you've shown, it works fine for me.  So obviously there is something different that you are NOT showing that is causing the problem.

Comment: Tell you what.  Why don't you create a new default project, and simply add the code you've shown to it (not all the other stuff you have in your actual code).  You will see it works correctly, which will prove my point.

Comment: Well, I do have a custom editor template for DateTime, but if the issue were there I think it would break all the other instances as well. Any other thing that comes to mind is that the Overview action is the default action of the application in RouteConfig. Then I guess I'll have to make a sample project myself and work out the difference.

Comment: You do have a point. But the GET binding seems kind of quirky in in ASP.NET MVC. There are a lot of other questions about it on SO. None of them helped me.

Comment: So you were right from the beginning, partly. I turned on IntelliTrace so i can see the exception thrown and caught during request processing and indeed it can't parse the date string. Why it is able to parse the exact same thing during POST request is so far beyond me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. HTTP GET requests are culture invariant, whereas HTTP POST requests respect current culture in ASP.NET MVC.

http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/11/21/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization.aspx

Comment: Ahh.. yes, of course.  Yes, that makes sense.  Because a get is part of the URL, the URL has to be usable by any culture.  Just goes to show, now matter how experienced you are, you can still learn new things...

Comment: I understand why they did it this way. But the user wont understand that. He still expects to enter the date in a way he is used to. And while you can write custom model binder, it would be nice if there was a configuration option to switch from invariant GET handling to one that respects globalization setting in Web.config

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bring the Model again into the view, you need to pass the ModelView back to the View like

```
return View(TimeAxis);
```

then, I think you do not have a controller called `Controller` do you? You might have a `HomeController` or something else, no?

in that case, please amend you form to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Overview", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
```

if for example you're `Overview` action is in the `Home` controller

---

all in all, your controller and view should be:

```
public ActionResult Overview(TimeAxisVM TimeAxis)
{
    return View(TimeAxis);
}
```

and

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Overview", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.From)

    @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.To)

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

---

here's the screencast of the code above: http://screencast.com/t/7G6ofEq0vZEo

Full source: http://ge.tt/1Uh80pK1/v/0?c

Comment: It really is @Html.EditorFor(model => model.From) with lower case 'm'. It's lambda function parameter, Model gets passed into it as model (you can call it whatever you want). Ok, lets call it "Home", I should not have used "Controller" as a stand in. And I want to do return View(new OverviewVM());, the way OverviewVM is constructed is hidden for clarity. I thought it was clear OverviewVM has TimeAxis as a property, sorry for that.

Comment: @balexandre - That's incorrect.  "model" is the lambda name, while Model is the name of the strongly typed Model object, it would be invalid and would not work to write `@Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.From)`

Comment: true, but you can always use `Model` as well and everything else if correct and it's working. - screencast: http://screencast.com/t/7G6ofEq0vZEo

Comment: @balexandre - You can't use Model as a lambda variable though.  You could do `model => Model`, but not `Model => Model`.  That wouldn't use the lambda model and just use the class level Model variable.